# Retrieve MySQL data using where clauses

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview, where-clause

I'm wonder how to use `WHERE` clauses to get the data from `MySQL` and finally load to android `listView` ? I want to get the **date**, **timeIn** and **timeOut** based on the name and month. This is what I have tried so far.

**GetData**

```
 public void getData(String name, String month) {
        class GetDataJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.7/Android/CRUD/retrieveInformation.php");


                // Depends on your web service
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                try {
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    inputStream = entity.getContent();
                    // json is UTF-8 by default
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Oops
                }
                finally {
                    try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result){
                myJSON=result;
                showList();
            }
        }
        GetDataJSON g = new GetDataJSON();
        g.execute();
    }

    protected void showList(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(myJSON);
            information = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_RESULTS);

            for(int i=0;i<information.length();i++){
                JSONObject c = information.getJSONObject(i);
                String date = c.getString(Config.TAG_DATE);
                String timeIn = c.getString(Config.TAG_TiME_IN);
                String timeOut = c.getString(Config.TAG_TIME_OUT);
                HashMap<String,String> info = new HashMap<String,String>();
                info.put(Config.TAG_DATE, date);
                info.put(Config.TAG_TiME_IN, timeIn);
                info.put(Config.TAG_TIME_OUT,timeOut);

                infoList.add(info);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    HomePage.this, infoList, R.layout.retrieve_data,
                    new String[]{Config.TAG_DATE,Config.TAG_TiME_IN,Config.TAG_TIME_OUT},
                    new int[]{R.id.date,R.id.timeIn,R.id.timeOut}
            );

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

**retrieveInformation.php**

```
<?php
  define('HOST','127.0.0.1:3307');
  define('USER','root');
  define('PASS','');
  define('DB','androiddb');

  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect');

  $name = $_GET['name'];

  $month = $_GET['month'];

  $sql = "select * from information WHERE name= '". $name."' and month = '".$month."'";

  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  $result=array();

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
      array_push($result,array('id'=>$row[0],'name'=>$row[1],'weather'=>$row[2],'date'=>$row[3],'status'=>$row[4],
      'time_in'=>$row[5], 'time_out'=>$row[6]));
  }

 echo (json_encode(array("result"=>$result)));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

I'm able to retrieve all the data from `MySQL` into android `listView` by
 using the code which I have posted in GetData. Now how can I retrieve
 data based on name and month ? I can't find any tutorial from
 google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to pass name/month as parameters to your PHP file.
The easiest way you could do this is by passing the parameters in the URL string (the easy way):

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost('http://192.168.1.7/Android/CRUD/retrieveInformation.php?name=SomeName&month=SomeMonth')
```

Then, name and month are seen as the $_GET variables you have in your PHP file.

But, because you want your code to be properly encoded, you would do something like this instead:

```
URI uri = new URIBuilder()
    .setScheme("http")
    .setHost("192.168.1.7")
    .setPath("/Android/CRUD/retrieveInformation.php")
    .addParameter("name", name)
    .addParameter("month", month)
    .build();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet( uri );
```

Note that I am using `HttpGet` in the second example rather than `HttpPost`

A quick suggestion on your PHP code so you don't have to remap all your indexes to their key names:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $result[] = $row; 
}
```

mysqli_fetch_assoc will set the key of array to the column name.  This will send ALL the columns.  If you don't want to send all the columns and only the 7 columns, you should modify your select query to this:

```
$sql = "select id, name, weather, date, status, time_in, time_out from information WHERE name= '". $name."' and month = '".$month."'";
```

And, also sanitize the $name and $month before your select query:

```
$name = mysqli_escape_string($name);
$month = mysqli_escape_string($month);
```

Here is your code updated to reflect the modifications:

```
<?php
define('HOST','127.0.0.1:3307');
define('USER','root');
define('PASS','');
define('DB','androiddb');

$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect');

$name = $_GET['name'];

$month = $_GET['month'];
$months = [
 'January' => '01',
 'February' => '02',
 'March' => '03',
 'April' => '04',
 'May' => '05',
 'June' => '06',
 'July' => '07',
 'August' => '08',
 'September' => '09',
 'October' => '10',
 'November' => '11',
 'December' => '12',
];

if (!isset($months[ $month ])) {
    die("Invalid month");
}

$month = $months[ $month ];


$name = mysqli_escape_string($con, $name);
$month = mysqli_escape_string($con, $month);
$sql = "select * from information WHERE name= '". $name."' and month = '".$month."'";

$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

$result=array();

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
    $result[] = $row; 
}

echo (json_encode(array("result"=>$result)));

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: you would replace where you have the `httppost` variable defined with my second code snippet

Comment: Although your PHP appears to be fine, I added some suggestions to your PHP so you can learn how to better use it (basically use mysqli_fetch_assoc instead of mysqli_fetch_array)

Comment: Thanks. Can you help me one more thing ? Currently my month is display January. How can I convert the month to 01 ?

Comment: also added on how to sanitize your variables.  Ideally, in Android you should convert January to a 01 just for the request.

Comment: Because I have insert my data by this format `2016-01-01` and my month is display as `January`..How can I convert to 01?

Comment: I posted a code example where it does the conversion in PHP.  I also put it in all the changes/suggestions I mentioned earlier.  I don't know how to do it in Android.

Comment: Look at the `$months` variable.  It remaps each month to the appropriate number.

Comment: Thanks..will try it later. Anything will let you know :)

Comment: I use your php code but no data get retrieved. I think is because of the month :/

Comment: what does the data look like in the table? is the month column an int? or a varchar?

Comment: The problem has been solved . Actually I have a date column and want to retrieve the month from the date column.

Comment: same thing here too http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php - that's another answer where you're giving unclear and misleading information on mysqli escape functions

Comment: @JohnJoe I made a mistake with mysqli_escape_string, it needs to include the $con variable. Updated my example.

Comment: Is it a must to use `mysqli_escape_string` ?

Comment: @JohnJoe not a requirement but it's a potentially serious problem if you don't - for example, someone could delete your data. Using PHP's PDO library (or other database libraries) makes it easier to deal with.  Anyway, the choice is up to you but it would be wise to use it.  Also, if someone enters an apostrophe for the name value, it would break your query and return no results (imagine someone's name is O'Malley or something).

Comment: Thanks for telling me all this :)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't put name and month in your HTTP request.

Try this

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.7/Android/CRUD/retrieveInformation.php?name="+name+"&month="+month);
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Do I need to change/add anything in `getData` ?

Comment: I don't think so. It might work if you've changed the URL.

Comment: @John Joe: Ye Min Htut is (correctly!) saying that if you're going to do a `$_GET['name'];` in your PHP ... then you'd darn well better have a parameter `name=xyz` in your URL.  The same with "month": both parameters need to be specified in the URL.  ALSO: look at Clayton's response.  He's saying the same thing.  Clayton also (correctly!) points out that you might wish to use `URIBuilder`, and you might use `HttpGet()` instead of "HttpPost()".

Comment: Yes. It's correct but you should sanitize your inputs (name and month) which are used as variables in sql query in order to protect sql injection.

Comment: Thanks, will go to have a look